# Virtualbox, windows host, no graphics on Ubuntu guests

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Every VM I try to make fails. VM's made on other machines and moved to this one also have issues.

Host system details:

> Host computer: Windows 10 Home, Version 10.0.18363.900
>
> CPU: AMD, Ryzen 2700X
>
> GPU: AMD, Vega64
>
> Graphics Driver: AMD, Radeon Software version 20.5.1
>
> Virtualbox: version 6.1.10. Extension pack installed.

I create a Linux VM, Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04, Server or Desktop, and start the installation steps. It always hangs at some point. The issue appears to be related to graphics.

However, I can switch to alternate tty's. Where I then cannot log in. Never did that before on the ISO, so not sure if that's normal.

This has also been observed with Debian 10.3

No matter which graphics driver I pick, 3D acceleration or not, 1 CPU, 4 CPU, 6 or 8 CPU, it makes no difference. It always stays like that.

A slightly different situation when I use an already created VM, which I download from https://www.osboxes.org/

I tested with Ubuntu 20.04.

The desktop version lets me enter the password on the login screen, but only when using VBoxSVGA. On first run, I got the intro screen, but as soon as I was done with that, the screen turned black. Except for the cursor. It was distinctly the black cursor from Ubuntu, not the white one from Windows. Going in and out of the VM screen, it consistently and immediately changed. But the rest of the screen was blank. Every run after that, I immediately got the black screen with the Ubuntu cursor.

Server edition, login works every time. Works as expected. But installing it from ISO does not.

I honestly have no idea what's causing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you in full screen mode , if yes maybe you hit this bug https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/19640

Comment: @EchoMike444 It sounds like it. I also tried enabling remote screen, and then RDP to the environment, but the result is identical.

Comment: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/19681

Comment: virtual box 6.1.10 is buggy , see comment from gombara

Comment: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/19664

Comment: @EchoMike444 I've downgraded to 6.1.4, result is unchanged though. I tried the `telinit` trick mentioned, no effect.

Comment: @EchoMike444 Just as an update: this is still happening in 6.1.16